# Highcharts candle/stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

is it possible to create this kind of chart using Highcharts? [image: See image].

I tried using highstock with candlestick's chart but I can't style it in a way that I need to. I will be glad if anyone could point me into right direction in proper styling or using other Highchart's chart type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this with a [`columnrange`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange) series. You can set up a per-point color scheme for your [data](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange.data) and provide your data in `[x, low, high]` format for default styling or use more advanced styling format:

```
{
    x: 1,
    low: 0,
    high: 4,
    name: "Point2",
    color: "#00FF00"
}
```

Very basic [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gd4gbnor/).

Comment: Here is an example showing something similar to the picture in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/h7yLza1j/2/ based on this method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great example.